# how to configure the scm repository?

Tags: svn

When I try to connect our scm repository in mac os it shows the following error:

> PROPFIND request faild on '/svn'.
>   RA layer request faild.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certain that you don't have a directory called svn in your repository, or perhaps your repository URL is wrong pr perhaps you haven't done `svnadmin create` to create a repository.